# Check if file/folder exist within bundle/project

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to figure out how to check if a folder exist within the project. The problem is that it can't find "MyFolder" and I think that it is because it is not looking inside the bundle but rather on the root of the phone. If I print current path it returns "/"

```
BOOL isDir;
BOOL exists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:@"MyFolder/" isDirectory:&isDir];
if (exists) {
    NSLog(@"exist");
    /* file exists */
    if (isDir) {
        /* file is a directory */
        NSLog(@"is dir");
    }
}
```

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing

```
fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
```

Then your code is right and the error is in other piece of your code.

The "/" returned is the root of your app, you can not look at the root of the phone

Or you do not have the "MyFolder" folder.